# what's wrong with this Regex? (Look-Ahead and Look-Behind)

Tags: regex, sdp

I try to extract the media description of a SDP package.

I have a line like

```
a=rtpmap:113 H264/90000
```

(after that there is always a carriage return)

I want everything after a=rtpmap:[number][whitespace] till the carriage return, without the return itself and constructed the following Regex, which doesn't work:

```
(?<=(a=rtpmap:[0-9]+\s)).*(?=\r)
```

If I do like

```
(?<=(a=rtpmap:[0-9]{3}\s)).*
```

I get at least a result, but the number after rtpmap isn't always 3 characters long. Why isn't the + working here?

Comment: What result do you want? in the above example?

Comment: I want only H264/90000; not the carriage return afterwards, not the a=rtpmap:[number][whitespace] before and no result, if there is no a=rtpmap:[number][whitespace]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Many regex engines do not support arbitrary- or variable-length lookbehind.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) .NET does but it's nearly alone in that regard.

In your case you should be better off using something like the following:

```
a=rtpmap:\d+ ([^\r]+)
```

and using the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

> (?<=(a=rtpmap:(\d+)\s)).*